# Ansible variable default to other variables that may be undefined

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have 3 variables a, b, and c. Either of

- a
- b and c

is/are defined (and perhaps even all 3 variables).

I would like to use a, or, if a is undefined, fall back to a concatenation of b and c. Something like this:

```
{{ a | default(b + '-' + c) }}
```

If a is defined, b and c should not have to be defined, but unfortunately with the above solution, ansible will complain about b not being defined.

The following works, but is butt-ugly:

```
{% if a is defined %}{{ a }}{% else %}{{ b + '-' + c }}{% endif %}
```

Isn't there some more readable way to do what I want? Preferably a concise one-liner, because I have a bunch of these variable combos.

Answer (score 0):

How about ?:

```
vars:
  my_default: "{{ (b | default('')) + '-' + (c | default('')) }}"
  my_real_value: "{{ a | default(my_default) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure though it's an improvement, because I have quite a few of those variable combos, and so I would have to have above two lines for every one of them, introducing another variable each. In the meantime I have solved it completely differently, as outlined in my own answer.

Comment: I didn't have the info about "the bunch of those" when I wrote the above. It definitely does not scale.

Comment: I know - I only added that after I saw your answer. Before, my question was lacking this bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to my own question, but a "how I solved it instead", and in fact in a better way, because, as I mentioned in the question:

> I have a bunch of these variable combos.

In fact, one-hundred and ten of those combos. So I figured I put them all in dictionaries and iterate over them.

Now I am creating a entries if they do not exist from b and c. This way, I always end up with a dictionary a regardless of whether it was configured directly, or via b and c. So I can just use a in my templates without any ifs, elses, or defaults. So the resulting templates are cleaner than any concise one-liner solution of the narrowly defined question could make them.

Only a and c are dictionaries, while b is constant for every host.

```yaml
- name: Create vars
  block:
    - name: Construct a entries from b and c
      set_fact:
        a: "{{ a | default({}) | combine({item.key : b + ':' + item.value|string}) }}"
      when: a is not defined or item.key not in a
      loop: "{{ c | default({}) | dict2items }}"
  when: b is defined
```